# Javascript or jQuery ScrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have a HTML Website with a fixed header height: 80px with: 100%; and a Anchor Menu like

```
<ol>
    <li>
            <a href="#anchor_one">anchor_one</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#anchor_two">anchor_two</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#anchor_three">anchor_three</a></li>
    </ol>
```

if i click on the menu the page always put the anchor point to the top (under the fixed menu)

i tried to put these in the a tag

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('anchor_one').scrollIntoView()">
```

but it´s always under the fixed header

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net might be very much helpful

Comment: I know but it´s for commercial Work, I´am not able to add a jsfiddle.net sorry. 

I only want to put the Jumping Anchro under the fixed header